Trying to install chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb using Gdebi Package installer keeps giving me a error
Trying to install chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb using gdebi Package installer keeps giving me a error status: Error: Dependency is satisfiable: libglib2.0-0 (>=2.33.14). I'm using the latest release of Ubuntu.


Try to update the system first, i.e. the currently installed software. In the console: sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade Or from the GUI package manager.

On Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS, I installed without problems. What is your system version?
Maybe search on google chrome-desktop-remote older version.
